# Overcoming inconsistent <br> selection behavior in contenteditable

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I noticed an odd behavior in Chrome where I attempted to select a bunch of div-br-div lines.

In this code:

```
  <section contenteditable>
  <div>--- end selection here ---</div>
  <div>Some -div-br-div- lines:</div>
  <div><br></div>
  <div><br></div>
  <div><br></div>
  <div><br></div>
  <div><br></div>
  <div><br></div>
  <div>--- start selection above this line ---</div>
  </section>
```

If I start selection above the "start selection" line, then move it up to the "end selection" line, I get the following behavior:

In Chrome and Brave, the starting as well as the next line are skipped:

[image: Chrome]

In Firefox, all the br lines are skipped:

[image: Firefox]

And in Safari, all the selected lines are highlighted:

[image]

How can I make Chrome not visually skip lines in selection and do the normal text-editor behavior similar to Safari?

Here's a demo where you can try selecting the lines:
https://jsfiddle.net/8r5m24t7/3/

Note that if I start selection with a non-br line (for example, with the word "start") it will select as it is supposed to:

[image: Chrome 2]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the lines are not "skipped". If you copy and then paste in a text editor, you will see that every newline has been copied. It is only about the  way, how the selection is visualized by the browser.

> How can I make Chrome not skip lines in selection

You should not try to do that at all. You are a content creater and so you are not responsible for how the browser is visualizing selection of whitespace characters.

Moreover you should create spaces between blocks with CSS and not with `<br>` tags which should be used only for a single newline in certain cases, so you will not have this case at all in a real document/application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By "skipped", I meant visually skipped. What I'd like is for the experience of selecting the text to be visually consistent and not look broken on Chrome if user begins selection with an empty line rather than one with a character.

Comment: I see. It in deed looks broken. Try to report an issue to the google developers: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en
I am afraid that the only other thing to do would be to create your own JS application that will recreate the job of the browser to render everything exactly how you wish which is not a good idea